# How to adjust the size of background image with browsers window using media queries

Tags: css

I have a background image in my website. I want to adjust the size of the my background image with browsers window using media queries. I am new to the concept of media queries, could you please show me how to that?

Thanks :)

In my CSS file:

```
.homepage{background-image:url(../images/work.jpg); background-repeat:no-repeat;}
```

In my HTML file

```
<body class="homepage">

</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a media query in your style sheet for specific screen resolutions say for example

```
@media all and (max-width: 1200px) and (min-width: 520px) {
  body {
    /* Now whatever styles you use here will be applicable for your specified screen widths */
  }
}
```

So coming to your issue, I assume you want your background of the body to auto adjust according to screen resolutions, you can try this, without using media queries..

```
html { 
    background: url('/* Path to image file */') no-repeat center center fixed; 
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply. Could you please tell me what should be the css code for `.homepage` If i want to keep it inside that media query. Thanks :)

Comment: simply keep the home page class in specific media query

Comment: but don't I have to set any width for my image? When the browser's window size is below 1200 the width of my image should change accordingly.. I am sorry if I sound stupid :)

Comment: I guess you just want to make the background stretch if the width of the window increases right? just use my CSS3 solution, just read the answer carefully